Nested, repeated comparatives?
Can someone please explain why the following construction is grammatical?

Josh is taller than Mary is taller than Helen.

I’ve come across this kind of phrasing before in all sorts of media (newspapers, magazines, books and what have you), so surely it must be acceptable grammar. I don’t know what it’s called though. I always found it odd how, from two independent clauses/sentences,

Josh is taller than Mary. Mary is taller than Helen.

the object (forgive me if the terminology is not quite right, I’m no grammarian) of the first can double as the subject of the second without some sort of relative construction like

Josh is taller than Mary, who is taller than Helen.

Doesn’t that violate some sort of rule about not having two stative verbs in one sentence?

*I like this pen is blue.

Also, at which point does this kind of nesting breaks down (if it ever does)?

Josh is taller than Mary is taller than Helen is taller than Isaac is
taller than…

Please and thank you.

A rose is a rose is a rose: that's the extent of it for me.

It's ungrammatical as 'Mary' is forced to be simultaneously object and subject in two different main clauses. (That's not to say it isn't used, tongue-in-cheek.) Compare 'I like Mary is tall', more obviously ridiculous.

Oy. Josh is taller than Mary is taller than Helen. "I’ve come across this kind of phrasing before in all sorts of media ... and what have you, so surely it must be acceptable grammar." The construction is odd and unclear, and if the media is social, it's below slang.

If Mary is 4” taller than Helen, then Josh must be more than 4” taller than Mary. This meaning seems obvious to me. In the same way, X > Y > Z seems obvious. And it can go on indefinitely. This is problematic according to some theories of grammar, apparently.

@Xanne For that you would say something like "Josh is more taller than Mary than Mary is than Helen", although It's a very clumsy construction.

@barmar But I don’t need to be clumsy, nor is this idiomatic.

Do you have any actual real-world examples of this, or is it just speculation?
